# Getting KeyError while merging pandas dataframe: Name: TimeStamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, datetime-format

**Getting error while trying to merge two dataframes on datetime column**

Where df1 has:

```
TimeStamp                Value1

01-01-2019 00:00:00       v1
```

And df2 will have:

```
TimeStamp                Value2

01-01-2019 9:23:52        v5
01-01-2019 10:33:52       v6
01-01-2019 11:43:52       v7
.
.
```

**What i need:**

```
TimeStamp                Value2    Value1

01-01-2019 9:23:52        v5        v1
01-01-2019 10:33:52       v6        v1
01-01-2019 11:43:52       v7        v1
.
.
```

**but currently df2 has:Empty dataframe, Columns:[TimeStamp, Value2]**

Then the expected output should be:

```
TimeStamp                        Value2    Value1

01-01-2019  00:00:00              None        v1
```

**What i tried:**

```
full_merged=df1.merge(df2, left_on=pd.to_datetime(df2['TimeStamp'],format='%Y-%m-%d'), right_on=pd.to_datetime(df1['TimeStamp'],format='%Y-%m-%d'),how='outer')
```

**Getting below error:**

```
raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 0 2019-08-27 Name: TimeStamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all reverse the *merge* direction. A more natural approach is that
the "base" DataFrame is *df2*.

The second point to correct is that the merge should be on *TimeStamp* column,
converted to *DateTime* and in case of *df2* - with the time part "cancelled"
(I assume that in both source DataFrames *TimeStamp* column is of *string* type).

Third detail is that:

- the object to merge to *df2* should be **only** *Value1* column from *df1*.
- the merge mode (*how*) should be *left*.

*Outer* merge mode would give weird result, e.g. if *df1* contained rows
with dates absent in *df2*.

In this case, the result would contain rows with *NaN* in both *TimeStamp*
and *Value2* and the *Value* from these rows from *df1*, without "source"
dates.

So, taking into account above remarks, I propose the following solution:

Generate a *Series* to merge:

- from *df1* with index set to *TimeStamp* column, coverted to *DateTime*,
- take only *Value1* column:

  ```
  val1 = df1.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df1.TimeStamp)).Value1
  ```

Then perform *merge* of:

- *df2* with index set to *TimeStamp* column, coverted to *DateTime*,
  and cancelled *time* part,
- with *val1*,
- on indices in both sources,
- in *left* mode,
- and drop the current index (create the new from scratch):

  ```
  df2.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df2.TimeStamp).dt.floor('d'))\
      .merge(val1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')\
      .reset_index(drop=True)
  ```

The result is:

```
             TimeStamp Value2 Value1
0  01-01-2019 09:23:52     v5     v1
1  01-01-2019 10:33:52     v6     v1
2  01-01-2019 11:43:52     v7     v1
```

So, although the merge was on *date* part only, the result still has
original *TimeStamp* from *df2*.

## Edit

Your code failed also because the actual format of both *TimeStamp* columns
was "day-month-year", whereas you specified `%Y-%m-%d` (year-month-day).
My advice: If not needed, don't specify the date / time format.
*pd.to_datetime* is clever enough to recognize the format from source data.

Comment: Thank you @Valdi_Bio for your response. While trying your answer got this error: TypeError('Cannot join tz-naive with tz-aware '
TypeError: Cannot join tz-naive with tz-aware DatetimeIndex. Probably we will need to make both tz unaware.

Comment: I created my test DataFrames from text source, then converted each *TimeStamp* column to *DataTime*, so both of them were "unaware". If you have one column "aware" and the second not, you should "align" them.